# Redux dynamic store hot loading

Tags: javascript, webpack, redux

I have multiple (~10) different independent redux components in my codebase that I test separately via different webpack entry points. They are very disparate components, with completely different state shapes etc.

eg.

```
/application1/*
/application2/*
```

Right now each one of them has its own `store.js`, `store.prod.js`, `store.dev.js` code for configuring the store.

However, all of this code is essentially identical, and it would be nice to centralise it.

I can create a shared store generating function in `/shared/store/` and have the root component of each 'application' pass in their own reducer, but I get stuck when it comes to the hot loading in `store.dev.js`:

```
export default function configureStore(rootReducer, preloadedState) {
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    preloadedState,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(thunk, api, createLogger()),
      DevTools.instrument()
    )
  )

  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
      const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers').default
      store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer)
    })
  }

  return store
}
```

Is there a way to dynamically hand the appropriate reducer path to the `module.hot.accept` code or do I need to maintain a separate `store.dev.js` for every component which has its own store?

If not, is there any other elegant solution?

Comment: Have you tried IE: `require(store+'../reducers/');` AKA an expression in your require.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it doesn't work. Webpack gives a warning: `Critical dependencies: 38:28-48 the request of a dependency is an expression` and React warns that it can't hot-load the reducer: `warning.js?8f69:14 <Provider> does not support changing store on the fly. `

Comment: if these applications are completed separated, you should manage them as different projects. If they are just 'sub-application` of your main app, you can re-design your state so that each 'sub-application' state lives under a key of your whole state.